# Terraform - Azure Service Principal deployment - insufficient permissions

Tags: azure-active-directory, terraform-provider-azure, azure-service-principal

I am trying to create azure service principal. I am connection to azure from my laptop using service principal, I have added required permissions, service principal (which I am using to connect to azure) is a member of global administrators, sp is a member of an application developer and application administrator role in azure AD. In order to connect to Azure I am using following PowerShell commands.

```
$ApplicationId = "aaa"
$AppPassword = "bbb"
$TenantId = "ccc"
$SecuredPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $AppPassword -AsPlainText -Force

$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList 
$ApplicationId, $SecuredPassword
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $TenantId -Credential $Credential
```

When I try run -  `terraform apply -var-file="variables.tfvars"` I am getting an error:

```
with azuread_application.azuread_app,
│   on service-principal.tf line 3, in resource "azuread_application" "azuread_app":
│    3: resource "azuread_application" "azuread_app" {
│
│ ApplicationsClient.BaseClient.Post(): unexpected status 403 with OData error: Authorization_RequestDenied: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

I was able to deploy other resources without any problems. I am using remote backend state file, located on Azure Container.

terraform code below:

```
data "azuread_client_config" "client_config" {}

resource "azuread_application" "azuread_app" {
  display_name = "sp_name"
  owners       = [data.azuread_client_config.client_config.object_id]
}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "azuread_sp" {
  application_id               = azuread_application.azuread_app.application_id
  app_role_assignment_required = false
  owners                       = [data.azuread_client_config.client_config.object_id]
}

resource "azuread_service_principal_password" "azuread_sp_password" {
  service_principal_id = azuread_service_principal.azuread_sp.object_id
}
```

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tested the same scenario in my environment using the below code and the `Service Principal` was successfully created from terraform.***

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    storage_account_name = "cloudshellansuman123" # replace with your storage account name
    container_name       = "test" #replace with your container name
    key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
    access_key = "ukyaH/Jxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx="#replace with your storage account access key
  }  
}

provider "azurerm" {
    features{}
  client_id="de398e56-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-20d07416ecb0"#replace with your service principal client ID which you are using to connect with Azure
  client_secret= "-IP7Q~uDLoxxxxxxxxxxxxRGtHMMXj7-.-lA"#replace with your service principal client Secret which you are using to connect with Azure
  tenant_id = "ab07xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx--xxx-620b694ded30"#replace with your AzureAD tenant ID which the subscription is a part of 
  subscription_id="8xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxae"#replace with your Subscription ID on Which the Service Principal has Owner/Contributor access
}


provider "azuread" {
  client_id="de398e-xx-x-x-x-x-x-x-x416ecb0"#replace with your service principal client ID which you are using to connect with Azure AD
  client_secret= "-IP7Q~uDLoxxxxxxxxxxxxxxGtHMMXj7-.-lA"#replace with your service principal client Secret which you are using to connect with Azure AD
  tenant_id = "ab0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx30"#replace with your AzureAD tenant ID which the subscription is a part of 
}

data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azuread_application" "terraform" {
  display_name = "Ansumantest"
  owners       = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
}

resource "azuread_application_password" "terraform" {
  application_object_id = azuread_application.terraform.object_id
}

 resource "azuread_service_principal" "terraform" {
   application_id = azuread_application.terraform.application_id
   owners         = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
 }
```

***For Testing I created a Service Principal which I am using to connect with Azure and granted all the same permissions that you have granted and also added  a `Owner` access on the subscription like below :***

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Output:**

[image]

***Note: Using the above code , you don't need again to connect to Azure using PowerShell. It will get authenticated directly using the `.tf` configuration. Also make sure to use Latest `AzureRM` and `AzureAD` provider Versions in terraform i.e. `2.95.0` & `2.17.0` respectively.***

Comment: OK, thx, will test it, and reg. to your code, you have secrets hardcoded in the tf file, its not secure I think.

Comment: Yes, works form me, there was one missing block in my tf code `provider "azuread"`. The question is how we can avoid hardcoding all these secrets in the .tf code.

Comment: @tester81, you can set it as variables or store those in environment variables in powershell .. For that you can refer this [Terraform document](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_secret)